# response.getOutputStream has already been called

Tags: java, servlets

Is there a way using which I can check whether getOutputStream has been called for a response or not?

Comment: Why would you want that ? `getOutputStream ` is an _idempotent_ call.

Comment: @Santosh I have an Interceptor which does some tasks, it gives an exception in case getOutputStream(ActionInvocation invocation.invoke()) is already been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to write a `ServletFilter` that intercepts the servlet requests, uses a [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to wrap the HttpServletResponse whose response.getOutputStream() would tell you that the method has been called and delegates the call to the wrapped `HttpServletResponse` to return the actual output stream.

Comment: How will that method tell whether response.getOutputStream was already called, like if the response is comitted, response.isComitted returns true.

Comment: The assumption is that this would be configured as the last filter in the chain so that it would be first to wrap the response that comes out of the servlet.

Comment: I already have an interceptor where I need to check this, I can not do this in ServletFilter

Comment: @Ankit, Interceptors can also be chained, right? Why not do this in a new interceptor and make sure this is the first one to read the output? I certainly don't have the complete context of the problem to say if this is the requirement or there can another way to address your actual use case in which this is one of the steps.

Comment: @Ankit, btw, is this needed only for one servlet/action or all?